# Puppeteer is not moving the mouse while using it inside docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, google-chrome, puppeteer

I'm trying to move the mouse with Puppeteer while running it inside a docker container while recording with ffmpeg the screen.

The issue is that every time I record with ffmpeg the mouse cursor is showing in the recording always in the center of the screen.

In order to remove it I tried to move the mouse away with `page.mouse.move()` and `page.mouse.click()`.

I tried also `page.hover()` and tried to use in all this cases each combination of `headless` `true` and `false`.

This is how I set up puppeteer (original code without headless option used):

```
browser = await puppeteer.connect({
            'browserWSEndpoint': endpoint,
            'defaultViewport': null
        });

const pages = await browser.pages();
const page = pages[0];
await page.goto(url);
console.log("Making page active.");
await page.bringToFront();
```

I add that if I connect to the container with VNC Viewer I'm perfectly able to move the cursor manually.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by installing xdotool with the docker image and then on the script using:

```
console.log("Hiding mouse")
let xdotool = spawn("xdotool", [
    'mousemove',
    '0',
    '0'
]);
```